# How to measure the memory usage of javascript JIT compilation and optimization?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, jit, memory-footprint

We have a huge legacy JS web application which suffers from performance problems. We are keep profiling our JS code to optimize the implementation and improve the performance. However, there is also possibility that the overhead of JIT optimization/de-optimization may also contribute to the slow performance in some cases.

Question
**How can I measure the memory footprint for JS code compilation and optimization compilation?**

Why I'm so keen on the memory footprint of JS engine itself? Our App is running on mobile devices, from high-end Surface Pro, iPad Pro to low end android devices (<150USD). So the memory footprint is critical for both the performance and stability of the App.

Comment: JS is almost *never* the perf bottleneck, unless we're talking animations. You say you're profiling, yet asking *us* for help? Ten bucks says that you're not batching DOM access, triggering forced sync layout, etc.

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks for your comment... yes we did profiling and figured out performance bottle necks from different places, including forced layout, too long synchronized operation and etc. But as you know, performance is always about to find the next critical bottle neck, which leads me to the question above... I'm not sure if that's the critical one now, thus why I'm looking for a way to measure and quantify the overhead.